# How can I override the 'map' constructor in a Grails domain class?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I need to perform some initialization when new instances of my domain class are created.

```
class ActivationToken {
    String foo
    String bar
}
```

When I do this I want bar to be initialized by code inside ActivationToken:

```
def tok = new ActivationToken(foo:'a')
```

I cannot see how to 'override' the 'constructor' to make this happen. I know in this case I could just add a normal constructor but this is just a simple example.

Comment: Can you not set a default value for `bar` on the domain?

Comment: The value I need to set is expensive to calculate so I don't want every default instance created by Hibernate et al to incur this cost

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The map constructor is coming from Groovy - not Grails in this case.  I did some experimentation, and this is what I came up with:

```
class Foo {
    String name = "bob"
    int num = 0

    public Foo() {
        this([:])
    }

    public Foo(Map map) {
        map?.each { k, v -> this[k] = v }
        name = name.toUpperCase()
    }

    public String toString() {
        "$name=$num"
    }
}

assert 'BOB=0' == new Foo().toString()
assert 'JOE=32' == new Foo(name:"joe", num: 32).toString()
```

Basically, it appears that you'll have to manually override the constructors if you need to process the property after construction.

Alternately, you can override individual setters, which is cleaner and safer in general:

```
class Foo {
    String name = "bob"
    int num = 0

    public void setName(n) {   
        name = n.toUpperCase()
    }

    public String toString() {
        "$name=$num"
    }
}

assert 'bob=0' == new Foo().toString()
assert 'JOE=32' == new Foo(name:"joe", num: 32).toString()
```

Note that the default value isn't processed, but that should be OK in most instances.

Comment: the constructor with the empty map gives me a StackOverflowException :(

Comment: My map constructor doesn't even get invoked... grails just calls the default constructor.

Comment: Running rails 3.3.11. This solution does not work

Answer (score 1):

The solution above is also good for cases where initializing an object from parameters in a web request, for example, where you wish to ignore extraneous values, catching Missing property exceptions.

```
public Foo(Map map) {
    try {
        map?.each { k, v -> this[k] = v }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```